# Output time and date with PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I'm having problems trying to get the time to display with php. I can get the date to work but not the time. The format it has to be in is 2:46PM on January 29 2017.
This is what I have to far.

```
echo date(' F j Y');
```

Comment: so show us what you're trying to use for the time, or RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php it's all in there.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this

```
echo date("g:i a, F j, Y ");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo date('g:i A F d Y');
```